# What's the best way to upload video on a personal website?

Tags: object, video, mp4, quicktime

What's the best way to play video clips on a personal website?

I'm coding my site from scratch and have the following code implemented on my site:

HTML:

```
<object data="example.mp4"></object>
```

CSS:

```
#ID object {width: #px; height: #px; margin: #px}
```

It seems to work with Safari, Chrome, and Firefox (haven't tried IE), however Safari and Firefox seem to cut off the play/pause button. Also, when I first go to the page in any browser, I see a Q (QuickTime logo). I'm working on a Mac, but why would this happen on my site, and not on other sites I visit?

In a nutshell, is there a better way to do this so that these things will not happen (alt video format or something)? I'm not opposed to hosting the video on Vimeo or an alternate sight if it would help avoid these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML5 video tag:

```
<video width="pixelswide" height="pixelshigh" controls>
<source src="example.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

It works on every brower (Opera 25+ and Firefox 21+). The only downside is that the controls are different on each browser.